# test1.c:7: error: syntax error before '{' token

Tags: c

I am trying to create a multiline macro and i am facing this error.

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    #define call(a) \
            if ((a)>0) \
              printf("printing a %d:"a)

    int main
    {
            int a =10;
            call(a);
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Can you wrap that whole thing in a `do...while(0)`?

Comment: missing comma in `printf`

Comment: `printf("printing a %d:"a)` should be `printf("printing a %d:",a)`

Answer (score 1):

`int main` needs to be written as `int main()`.

Also, there should be no whitespace after the final `\` of a multi-line macro. That can cause spurious compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

C function declaration requires parentheses, with or without parameters.

```
int f   { ... } // incorrect
int f() { ... } // correct
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing "," in prinf() function befor variable "a".

```
   #include<stdio.h>

    #define call(a)\
        if ((a)>0)\
          printf("printing a %d:",a)

int main()
{
        int a =10;
        call(a);
        return 0;
}
```